# ListTablesSegmentedAsync disregards the continuation token

Tags: .net-core, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I am trying to use ListTablesSegmentedAsync and it doesn't seem to be using the continuable token. I am using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table v1.0.8 and trying to list tables on the storage emulator. Here's my simplified test code:

```
public async Task ListTablesTest(
    CloudTableClient client)
{
    TableContinuationToken continuationToken = null;
    TableResultSegment ret;
    
    ret = await client.ListTablesSegmentedAsync(
        string.Empty,
        5,
        continuationToken,
        CancellationToken.None);

    continuationToken = ret.ContinuationToken;

    ret = await client.ListTablesSegmentedAsync(
        string.Empty,
        5,
        continuationToken,
        CancellationToken.None);
}
```

Both calls to ListTablesSegmentedAsync return the first 5 tables (alphabetically). The token returned from the first call looks correct, as far as I can tell. Am I missing something? Maybe this doesn't work in the emulator?

Comment: Hello, if the answer is helpful, could you please accept it as answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you're using the latest version of [azure storage explorer 1.16.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-storage-manage-with-storage-explorer?tabs=windows#download-and-install) and [azure storage emulator 5.10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-emulator#get-the-storage-emulator).

In my test, I'm also using `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table v1.0.8`, it can list next 5 tables by using ContinuationToken:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response, Ivan. I verified that I'm running storage emulator version 5.10. The test code I posted still returns the first 5 tables in both calls to ListTablesSegmentedAsync. It looks like you're running the code I posted?

Comment: @ChrisInSeattle, yes, I just use your code. can you share us the Main method you're using to call the `ListTablesTest` method? it may be the async issue.